# The value of attribute "rendered" associated with [...] must not contain the '<' character

Tags: jsf, el, rendered-attribute

I have numeric values in a `p:dataTable`. When the value is less than 0, a "-" symbol should be inserted instead of a value.

I tried using `c:if`, which doesn't work. I was reading and people suggest the `rendered` flag.

The code is:

```
<p:column headerText="Valor">
    <h:outputText rendered="${valor.valor > 0}" value="${valor.valor}" />
    <h:outputText rendered="${valor.valor <= 0}" value="${valorMB.noDato}" />
</p:column>
```

and the server give me this error:

> The value of attribute "rendered" associated with an element type "h:outputText" must not contain the '<' character

If I use `c:if` the table appears without data:

```
<c:if test="#{valor.valor > 0}">
    <h:outputText value="#{valor.valor}" />
    <c:otherwise>
        <h:outputText value="-" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:if>
```

How can I resolve my problem?

Comment: Should use # in rendered="#{valor.valor > 0}". The property valor must be an int. The value of the h:outputText in valor <= 0 should be the - character you want to show.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use keyword based EL operators instead of symbol based EL operators:

```
<h:outputText rendered="#{valor.valor gt 0}" value="#{valor.valor}" /> <!-- valor.valor > 0 -->
<h:outputText rendered="#{valor.valor le 0}" value="-" /> <!-- valor.valor <= 0 -->
```

- `lt` (lower than)
- `gt` (greater than)
- `le` (lower than or equal)
- `ge` (greater than or equal)
- `eq` (equal)
- `ne` (not equal)
- `and`
- `or`

Comment: Note: EL is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting that error because "<" character is illegal in string inside xml. You should use Expression Language way of comparing.

In your situtation you should use `le` which means means ***less than or equal***.

Change  `"${valor.valor <= 0}"`  to  `"${valor.valor le 0}"`